# Roles and permissions not updating when DB changed in strapi

Tags: mongodb, strapi

I am using **strapi** in my **node.js** project with **mongoDB**. When the database is fresh, all the roles and permissions are created properly. After that when i create a new content type(new collection) either from strapi CLI or from strapi admin UI it is creating the related roles and permissions properly. But when i switch the DB, the roles related to new content type are not appearing.

Comment: Provide proper explanation with code

Comment: This is all done using strapi CLI and admin UI. No special code used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No Answer - but can confirm the same situation.

To clarify - it seems that the Users-Permissions plugin stores information about permissions at the point of creation.

When you then move the types (models) to a another server with DIFFERENT mongodb (but maybe same user) the Role-Permissions do not pickup on the fact that new models are available (and even showing permissions for models that no longer exists).

I.e. there is 0 checks it seems that syncs models as configured...

The only way it to migrate the user and user-permissions - but that is RISKY.

Answer (score 0):

We got a fix for this in latest version of Strapi (v3.0.0-alpha.14.5)